# Nextjs requesting dev site Strapi api from local webapp causing CORS issue

Tags: next.js, cors, strapi

On our dev site we have a `Strapi` integration that is deployed in an isolated state away from our NextJS application.

The `Strapi` backend is accessed via `/api/*`, an example is getting a list of articles, so the endpoint is `/api/articles`.

Locally, we want to hit the dev site URL instead of having to spin strapi up locally. So we want to hit `https://dev.our-website.com/api/articles`.

However, I get the following error when trying to run the following in the browser console on our local webapp @ `http://localhost:3000`

#### Request

```
fetch('https://dev.our-website.com/api/articles', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer bearer token is here',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
```

#### Response

```
Access to fetch at 'https://dev.our-website.com/api/articles' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode
to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Running the following request works fine when it on the browser console on the dev site, just for a reference that the endpoint does work, just that CORS is blocking the request on the dev site from localhost.

#### Request

```
fetch('/api/articles', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer bearer token is here',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
```

I'm unsure if there is anywhere in our NextJs application that we can allow requests to the dev site from localhost? As the Strapi integration is isolated from the NextJS application, I'm unsure how to go about it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you configured the server for CORS? If you haven't, you should. If you have, edit your question and add your CORS configuration.

Comment: @jub0bs I don't, that's really my question I don't know how. There are no other endpoints other than Strapi and no pages are currently rendered via SSR.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/middlewares.html#cors?